# PHP String Replace variable div in loop

Tags: php, javascript, string, loops

**EDIT:**

**[I have posted my full code here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hqajw)**

**What I've got**
 - Click on an input box.
 - The string in the box is displayed in a div.

**I want to:**

- Click on an input box.
- The string in the box is trimmed.
- The new string is put in a div.

**Where I am lost:**

- Where the string replace goes in the loop to change the variable that the HTML output.

---

---

I am using a mix of PHP, JS & Jquery to echo the contents of a directory into a table. I have an input box value that I want to be duplicated in a div - I have done this, but I would like to change the string before it goes to the div.

I think I know the appropriate code as per below, but I don't know where to place it to make it work - various attempts gave me server error on page load.

**LINE TO BE AMENDED**

This: `document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = $(this).val(); \"`

Becomes: `document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = &replaceWith \"`

**HOW I THINK THIS CAN BE DONE** - *but not sure where it goes*

```
$TextBoxStr = $(this).val();
$removeThis = array("&#91&#91;http://www.example.com/$dirArray[$index]&#124;", "&#93;&#93;"); 
$replaceWith = array("", "");
```

**CODE EXTRACT**

```
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
        {
            if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "." && $dirArray[$index] != "index.php" && $dirArray[$index] != "error_log" )
            {
            echo "<TR>
            <td><input id='thistext$index' type='text' onclick='this.select();' onfocus=\"document.getElementById('show_hide').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('show_hide2').innerHTML = 'Copy this text, it will display as: '; document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = $(this).val(); \"
     onblur=\"document.getElementById('show_hide').style.display='none';\" value='&#91&#91;http://www.example.com/$dirArray[$index]&#124;$dirArray[$index]&#93;&#93;' /></td>
                </TR>";
            }
        }
    echo "</TABLE><div id='show_hide'><div id='show_hide2'></div><div id='target'></div></div>
";
    ?>
```

Comment: Can I get a comment from the downvoters please? I'm happy to improve this post if I can.

Comment: What is it that you are looking to replace?

Comment: `$TextBoxStr = $(this).val();` Is that a PHP variable trying to be assigned thru JS?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please provide more details with some example or something like that? BTW, I didn't do downvote. LOL

Comment: You seem to be very confused about what happens on the client and server side. JS/jQuery runs on the client, PHP on the server, either when creating the page in the first place or in response to AJAX queries.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks for the comment, I have edited my post to include a link to my full code for perspective & what I want to achieve.

Comment: @tymeJV I suppose I want it to say `$TextBoxStr = [the_value_of_the_text_box`. I have also edited my post above. Thanks.

Comment: You're still confused about the order of operations. PHP runs, outputs a web page, the PHP script ends, and the output is sent to the browser. Anything the user enters into the form can't be put into PHP variables, because the PHP script is no longer running.  You can get inputs into PHP variables when the form is submitted and a new script instance runs. Or you can run Javascript that performs AJAX calls, which also invoke new scripts.

Comment: @Barmar The variable I need is before the user changes anything. For each loop I would like the input box to have a value of `xyz123xyz` with the attribute of `document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = 123` but I don't know where/how to strip `xyz123zyz` to `123`. I think it needs to be at the beginning of each loop. Any user entry has been dealt with later in the code (see my full code if needed at the top of my post). The first time the user clicks I want `123` not `xyz123xyz`.

Comment: If it happens when the user clicks, it's TOO LATE. PHP is already done by the time the user sees the page. You have to do what you want with Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the quick response. So in JS/jquery could I do something along the lines of: 1. Loop through all input boxes 2. Find input box value 3. Amend string to new string 4. Add element attribute  doc.getElemendbyID(target).innerHTML = new string

Comment: Something like that. In jQuery it's `$("#target").text(newstring)`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, or perhaps: All input boxes have 'on focus do thisfuction` then the function is JS which is 1. Get value, 2. Change value, 3. Put value in Div.